# anaconda_build tutorial fails on MacOS High Sierra: Library not loaded: libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib

Tags: python, anaconda

I am following [this official guide](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tutorials/build-pkgs-skeleton.html) for building a package for anaconda based on a skeleton. I just want to build the example package used in the tutorial, which is *pyinstrument*.

I am using anaconda2 version 4.5.11 under MacOS High Siera (10.13.6).

When running the command `conda_build pyinstrument`, I am getting the following error ([full output here](https://pastebin.com/g81m4YwU)):

> File
>   "/Users/me/anaconda2/envs/blbuild/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cffi/vengine_cpy.py",
>   line 159, in load_library
>       raise VerificationError(error) cffi.error.VerificationError: importing
>   '/Users/me/anaconda2/envs/blbuild/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/_Cryptography_cffi_4ed9e37dx4000d087.so':
>   dlopen(/Users/me/anaconda2/envs/blbuild/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/_Cryptography_cffi_4ed9e37dx4000d087.so,
>   2): Library not loaded: @loader_path/../../../libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib
>   Referenced from:
>   /Users/me/anaconda2/envs/blbuild/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/_Cryptography_cffi_4ed9e37dx4000d087.so   Reason: image not found

I have already tried reinstalling openssl via brew, because I found this recommendation when searching SO for the error message, it had no effect on the error though. My openssl version from brew is 1.0.2p in case that matters.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to finally resolve this issue. The solution was to manually install a package that seems to be required:

```
conda install cryptography
```